# ¿Qué nombre tienen los adjetivos que coinciden con su definición?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, adjetivos, lingüística

¿Existe alguna palabra para representar los adjetivos que coinciden con su definición? Por ejemplo, *esdrújula* es una palabra esdrújula, por lo tanto, es un adjetivo que cumple con su propia definición.

¿Estas palabras tienen alguna clasificación en particular?

Comment: Bienvenido, Ramiro, tu pregunta es muy interesante y yo mismo te he votado positivo para animarte a seguir participando, pero desafortunadamente esta pregunta ha sido ya formulada antes, por lo que debo marcarla como duplicada.

Comment: @Charlie vaya, no me di cuenta. Al menos esta pregunta servirá como "guía" a la otra pregunta, ya que el título de esta es más fácil de encontrar...

Answer (score 3):

Esta propiedad de las palabras es de algún modo tan "metalingüística", que no creo que haya un término oficial (no he podido encontrar ninguno). Sin embargo, Kurt Grelling y Leonard Nelson ya observaron que definir esta propiedad lleva a paradojas. En la [paradoja de Grelling-Nelson](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradoja_de_Grelling-Nelson), utilizan el término (inventado) **autológica** para referirse a una palabra que se describe a sí misma, como por ejemplo "esdrújula, polisílaba, corta". Del mismo modo, denominan **heterológica** a una palabra que no se describe a sí misma.

Entonces, hay ciertas palabras en las que la pregunta "¿es esta palabra autológica?" lleva a paradoja o ambigüedad. Por ejemplo:

- ¿Es "heterológica" una palabra autológica? Si es autológica, entonces por definición es heterológica. Y si es heterológica, entonces se describe a sí misma y por tanto es autológica. Por tanto, ni "sí" ni "no" son respuestas válidas.
- ¿Es "autológica" una palabra autológica? La respuesta puede ser "sí", pero también puede ser "no". La palabra "autológica" es autológica si y solo si se describe a sí misma, es decir si y solo sí es autológica. Esto es una tautología, por lo que "sí" y "no" son respuestas igualmente válidas.

En el artículo de Wikipedia hay otros casos interesantes. Mi conjetura es que, dados los problemas que plantea la definición de esta propiedad, probablemente no está definida oficialmente.